# Sacar el valor de un select en un modal y un query

Tags: php, mysqli, sql, modal

hace unos dias un compañero me ayuda a traspasar los datos de una tabla a un modal, en ellos hay un select que recibe los estado según el valor que tengan y salen seleccionado. Bien pero ahora es más complicado, trasporto el nombre que trae el campo pero el select lo genera un while de SQL y no se como hacer que detecte el nombre marcado.

**Con esto mandamos el contenido del span al modal:**

```
<td class="otrotdfgaz" id="select2-2<?php echo $resta['id']; ?>">
  <?php
    if($resta['idCliente'] == 0) echo "<span>Almacén</span>";
     else{
    ?>
    <span><a href="ver-cliente.php?ID=<?php echo $resta['IdUsuario']; ?>"><?php echo $resta['Nombre']; ?></span></a><span>
  <?php  } ?> 
</td>
```

**Con esto pasamos el valor a la id del select, para que reciba el valor:**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.referencias', function(){
      var id=$(this).val();
      var Stock=$('#select2-2'+id).children('span').first().text();

      $('#referencias').modal('show');
      //alert(Stock);
      if(Stock == 'Almacén')
      $('select#select2-2').val('0').trigger('change');
        else
      $('select#select2-2').val('<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>').trigger('change');
      });
  });
</script>
```

**Con esto recibimos el valor:**

```
 <select id="select2-2" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-2">
     <option value="0">Almacén</option>
   <?php
     //var_dump($_GET);
     $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Usuarios");
     mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
      while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
   ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Nombre']; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>                                                        
 </select>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el valor o texto de que select quieres obtener, si me digeras de cual quiere obtenerlo podría intentar darte una respuesta

Comment: No quiero obtenerlo de un select,, si te fijas veras que la infomación del span la pasamos al modal y al select

Comment: Con esta línea intentas seleccionar el usuario correspondiente, si no me equivoco: `$('select#select2-2').val('<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>').trigger('change');` pero según otras respuestas parece que es mejor hacerlo así: `$('select#select2-2 option[value=<?php echo $res['IdUsuario']; ?>]').attr('selected','selected');`. No sé si con esto se soluciona tu problema ya que también depende de en qué momento estés ejecutando este código, si está la lista de usuarios cargada o no

Comment: Nop, no me soluciona el problema, la verdad que tampoco se muy bien como explicartelo mejor

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste?

Comment: Según entiendo lo que quieres es que se seleccione un `option` del `select` en relación a un valor  traído desde la base de datos, ¿Es esto correcto?

Comment: Kevin mas o menos, mas bien el selected tiene que recoger el valor que viene del <span>. Esto ya lo hice pero como todas las opciones del select las trae una base de datos, ya no se como hacerlo

Comment: En tu javascript `$res['IdUsuario']` que te trae un valor único o mas de uno, tiene que ver algo con `$res['IdUsuario']` del `while` o son consultas diferentes

Comment: Trae un valor unico, por eso luego hago la consulta en el select, en el value IdUsuario y luego Nombre, para que detecte por el value que cliente esta seleccionado

Comment: Hola Sigo sin poder solucionarlo, alguna idea de alguien???